# Is Access-Control-Allow-Origin required for the preflight AND the actual request?

Tags: http, cors, http-accept-header

I am implementing a router to process all web requests.

OPTIONS requests come in and I am responding with:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Vary: Origin');
```

And also I am sending all those for the GET/POST/PUT/DELETE requests.

Is sending those headers for those "real" requests unnecessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) is the (somewhat dry) source of truth for the CORS protocol; you can find answers to all your questions about CORS in there; see, in particular,

- [4.7. CORS-preflight fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch), and
- [4.9. CORS check](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-check)

Some CORS response headers are only used in preflight responses:

- [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods)
- [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)
- [`Access-Control-Max-Age`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age)
- [`Access-Control-Allow-Local-Network`](https://wicg.github.io/local-network-access/#http-headerdef-access-control-allow-local-network) (which is part of [Local Network Access](https://wicg.github.io/local-network-access/), a recent extension to the CORS protocol)

Other CORS response headers are used in both the preflight response and the actual response:

- [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)
- [`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials)

> Is sending those headers for those "real" requests unnecessary?

Note that, if one or both of those headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`) are actually needed in the preflight response, they're also needed in the actual response.

Finally, one CORS response header is only used in the actual response: [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers).

The case of the [`Vary` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary) is interesting. Since, [in theory](https://httpwg.org/http-core/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics-latest.html#OPTIONS), responses to `OPTIONS` requests are not cacheable (outside of browsers' preflight cache), the `Vary` header should have no place in such responses. However, some caching intermediaries do allow their users to cache responses to `OPTIONS` requests, and omitting the `Vary` header from those responses may lead to [Web cache poisoning](https://portswigger.net/web-security/web-cache-poisoning).

This difficulty is a good indication that you shouldn't be implementing CORS by manually setting response headers. Instead, rely on [a good CORS middleware library](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/) that can abstract all this complexity for you.